# CakePHP 3.x catch selected controller from logging if MissingControllerException occurs

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP 3.x how can I catch selected controller names from logging in error.log file if MissingControllerException occurs.

Currently I am having loggs e.g.:

```
2022-02-17 09:32:34 Error: [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller class AAA could not be found.
```

I tried to write own MyExceptionRenderer.php in src/Error folder:

```
 namespace App\Error;

 use Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer;

 class MyExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer{   
     public function missingController($error){
         // Logic if AAA occuress do sth, e.g. redirect to selected page
     }     
 }
```

In app.php I added:

```
'Error' => [
    'errorLevel' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
    'exceptionRenderer' => 'App\Error\MyExceptionRenderer',
    'skipLog' => [],
    'log' => true,
    'trace' => true,
],
```

But it does not work

Comment: You'll have to be a little more specific as to what is wrong, as "_doesn't work_" could mean anything.

Comment: By not working, I mean that I still have the Error message for e.g. AAA missing controller in my error.log file, and the code for e.g. redirecting in missingController function is not run. I only see for e.g. AAA missing controller the 404 error page which is coded Template/error

Comment: My whole question relates to the issue that I need several missing constrollers which names are known for me, not to be logged in the error.log file, but to have a different operation e.g. redirect to selected page or save file in server etc

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code shown. You'll have to do some debugging, like check whether your exception renderer/config is actually being used. That being said, why do you need to handle this via missing controllers in the first place? Why not create those controllers and perform the desired actions from there?

Comment: I don't want to create controllers because there would be a huge number of nearly empty controllers with the same function. Is there an option to exclude only selected urls (MissingControllerException) from logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I don't see anything wrong with shown code, I've tried it 1:1 and it works fine for me using CakePHP 3.10.2, the `missingController()` method is being invoked as expected.

If your renderer is being used, but the method is not being invoked, then you'll have to debug the core exception renderer that you're extending, and figure out what exactly is happening when `\Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer::_customMethod()` should be invoked.

That being said, I'd probably use a custom middleware for this instead, as you're not actually going to do exception rendering. Put it after the error handler middleware and catch the exceptions that you want to catch, something along the lines of this:

```php
// in src/Middleware/MissingControllerHandlerMiddleware.php

namespace App\Middleware;

use Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException;
use Cake\Utility\Hash;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class MissingControllerHandlerMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Invoke method.
     *
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request The request.
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response The response.
     * @param callable $next Callback to invoke the next middleware.
     * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface A response
     */
    public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $next)
    {
        try {
            return $next($request, $response);
        } catch (MissingControllerException $exception) {
            $class = Hash::get($exception->getAttributes(), 'class');
            if ($class === 'AAA') {
                return $response->withHeader('Location', 'https://example.com/missing-aaa-controller-redirect');
            }
            
            if ($class === 'BBB') {
                // ...
            }

            // ...

            throw $exception;
        }
    }
}
```

```php
// in src/Application.php

public function middleware(MiddlewareQueue $middlewareQueue): MiddlewareQueue
{
    $middlewareQueue
        ->add(new ErrorHandlerMiddleware(Configure::read('Error')))

        ->add(new \App\Middleware\MissingControllerHandlerMiddleware())

        // ...

    return $middlewareQueue;
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Middleware > Creating Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/middleware.html#creating-middleware)**